# Read rcon command response

Tags: java

I want to send rcon command to server using java, to do this I'm using the following library  https://github.com/Kronos666/rkon-core
When i run command like this

```
Rcon rcon = new Rcon("127.0.0.1", 27015, "mypassword".getBytes());

// Example: On a minecraft server this will list the connected players
String result = rcon.command("list");

// Display the result in the console
System.out.println(result);
```

My server show response in console `Gc connection established from...` and so on

but in java app i have the empty result, it's not null, it's just empty

```
String result = rcon.command("list");
```

How can i take response from server using rcon protocol?

Comment: Did you upload the plugin to the server?

Comment: @YvanWatchman Thank for response, which plugin do you mean?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/Kronos666/rkon-core/releases/

Comment: Oh whoops, well it is the library...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try {
    Rcon rcon = new Rcon("127.0.0.1", 27015, "mypassword".getBytes());
    String result = rcon.command("list");
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    String result = "Authentication failed";
}
```

Comment: it's absolutely same as i do

Comment: There are not any exception, the problem is , i can't get response but command is work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Finally I write my own implementation:

```
public final class RconClient implements AutoCloseable {

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 4096;

    private final Socket socket;

    private final RconData data;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RconClient.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstructorShouldNotThrowExceptions")
    public RconClient(final String host,
                      final int port,
                      final byte[] password) throws IOException {

        this.socket = new Socket(host, port);

        final RconData requst = request(new RconData(RconData.AUTH, password));

        if (requst.getId() == -1) {
            LOG.error("Wrong password or ip to connect to rcon");
            throw new LoginException(host, port);
        }

        this.data = read();

    }



    public String command(String command) throws IOException {
        command = "get5_status";
        final RconData response = request(new RconData(command.getBytes()));
        return new String(response.getPayload(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    public RconData request(RconData packet) throws IOException {
        try {
            write(packet);
            return read();
        } catch (final SocketException exception) {
            socket.close();
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    private void write(RconData packet) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(packet.getPayload().length + 14);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        buffer.putInt(packet.getPayload().length + 10);

        buffer.putInt(packet.getId());
        buffer.putInt(packet.getType());
        buffer.put(packet.getPayload());

        buffer.put((byte)0);
        buffer.put((byte)0);

        socket.getOutputStream().write(buffer.array());
        socket.getOutputStream().flush();
    }

    private RconData read() throws IOException {
        byte[] packet = new byte[MAX_SIZE];
        int packetSize = this.socket.getInputStream().read(packet);

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(packet, 0, packetSize);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        if (buffer.remaining() < 4) {
            throw new WrongPacketException();
        }

        int size = buffer.getInt();

        if (buffer.remaining() < size) {
            throw new WrongPacketException();
        }

        int id = buffer.getInt();
        int type = buffer.getInt();

        byte[] payload = new byte[size - 10];
        buffer.get(payload);

        buffer.get(new byte[2]);

        return new RconData(id, type, payload);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.socket.close();
    }
}
```

Where RconData it's simple POJO with `byte[] password` property,